# How do I control the rotation of my servo?

Tags: servo

```cpp
#include <Servo.h> // servo library
Servo servo;     
int trigPin = 5;    
int echoPin = 6;   
int servoPin = 7;
int led= 10;
long duration, dist, average;   
long aver[3];   //array for average

void setup() {       
  Serial.begin(9600);
  servo.attach(servoPin);  
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);  
  servo.write(0); // close cap on power on
  delay(100);
  servo.detach(); 
} 

void measure() {  
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(15);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  dist = (duration/2) / 29.1; // obtain distance
}

void loop() { 
  for (int i=0; i<=2; i++) {  
  // average distance
  measure();               
  aver[i] = dist;            
  delay(10); // delay between measurements
  }
 
  dist = (aver[0]+aver[1]+aver[2])/3;    

  if (dist < 50) { // Change distance as per your need
    servo.attach(servoPin);
    delay(1);
    servo.write(0);  
    delay(3000);       
    servo.write(150);    
    delay(1000);
    servo.detach();      
  }

  Serial.print(dist);
}
```

This is my first time in robotics. The servo is a Tower Pro SG90. It rotates over 360° and ony spins in one direction, but I want it to rotate for just about 90° and to rotate back to its original place after. This is the code I used. I'm making a trash bin where the lid automatically opens.

Comment: Please no code as image. copy and paste the code as text and format it correctly by selecting it in the question editor and clicking on the `{}` button

Answer (score 0):

You should buy a normal servo, not a servo with continuous rotation. The Tower Pro SG5010, for example, should basically meet your needs.
But depending on the size of the bin and the mechanical control of the lid, you may want to choose a servo with greater actuating force.

Answer (score -1):

A continuous rotation servo cannot be set to specific angles, only specific speeds. That's the point for continuous rotation servos.

So for your trash bin you should buy a normal servo (not continuous rotation). Such servo can be moved to specific angles between 0 and 180°.